# Why does NodeJS/Javascript insist these variables are undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, undefined

I've been grappling with this issue for about an hour now, here is the offending code:

```
const t = games[0];
for (const mvar in t) {
    if (t.hasOwnProperty(mvar))
        console.log(`${mvar}: ${t.mvar}`);
}
```

The output is:

```
appid: undefined
name: undefined
playtime_forever: undefined
img_icon_url: undefined
img_logo_url: undefined
has_community_visible_stats: undefined
```

However, the WebStorm debugger says this value is not undefined as such:
[image]

Are there any other reasons that this could be?

Comment: What is `console.log(games[0])`?

Comment: See the linked question and answers. You're looking for: ``console.log(`${mvar}: ${t[mvar]}`);`` (note the `[` and `]`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`t` has no property named `myVar`.

You want `t[myVar]` to get the property with that name.

Comment: Fairly obvious and common duplicate, yes? :-)